# How to add predicates to custom entity models?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-optifine

I have been trying to make a boss fight in Minecraft and I have re-textured an armor stand to be the boss model, but when you spawn a normal armor stand it shows as the boss (without arms) as well.
How can I use predicates to make it so only the actual boss shows as the boss if it is holding a diamond sword with custom model data? Thank you to anyone that helps.

[image]

Comment: What mod are you using to get custom entity models?

Comment: I am not using any mods i am using a resource pack I created

Comment: unless optifine counts

Comment: Of course OptiFine is a mod! And it's quite relevant to this question, because Vanilla does not have custom entity models and there are multiple mods that implement it differently.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how i would do predicates with the custom entity?

Comment: No, I don't use OptiFine. But I've corrected the tags, so now people who know about it can find this question easier.